# Как определить на какой элемент нажали в WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

С помощью WebGLSpins отображаю массив стрелок(спины), нужно по нажатию (_handelMouseDown) вернуть координаты выбранного спина. Подскажите, как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Я не работал с WebGL, потому опишу логику как это делаю на Canvas. Во время клика можно легко достать координаты клика. Далее есть метод `isPointInPath` (это если элемент был создан через `new Path2D`), который позволят узнать, находится ли эти координаты внутри какого-то элемента. Ну и обратным перебором я смотрю какому элементу она принадледжит. Просто дело в том, что в Canvas нет понятия "слой", кто последний отобразился тот и выше, потому перебор идёт в обратном порядке

Comment: Комментарий выше дает корректный ответ, однако уточню:
Для WebGL возможно советовал бы почитать что такое AABB (Axis Aligned Bounding Box). Данный алгоритм прост и позволяет определить, находится ли курсор внутри фигуры. Есть еще варианты с радиусом окружности и с поворотом этого box-а, но это уже нужно читать отдельно.

Так же, советовал бы почитать про quadtree. Это способ оптимизации, который позволит вам ограничить список элементов, которые необходимо проверить, чтобы не пробегать по всем элементам на экране.